# Is there any information or sample or tutorial on how to use OpenCV HAL to accelerate my code?

Tags: c++, opencv

I noted that OpenCV 3 RC1 has a library called HAL which is for accelerating core functionality of OpenCV.

Is there any way that I can use this library to accelerate my code?

Is there any document/tutorial/... on how to use this library?

I want a way to accelerate my code so it can be run fast on Intel and ARM processors.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand it well then HAL is just a convenient, IPP-like, low-level API to accelerate OpenCV for different platforms (by hiding low-level operations i.e. core, imgproc, … => HAL) and to enable hardware vendors to implement accelerated imaging and vision algorithms.

OpenCV already had some acceleration API (i.e. parallel framework or OpenCL) and HAL fits into this sequence as a new one, HAL has a primary focus on enabling mobile and embedded systems and can be used by high-level libraries or applications directly.

The function set can be found whithin the `cv::hal` namespace - take a look at the documentation of [HAL module](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d3/d17/hal_8hpp.html) for the implemented functions.

Methinks you shouldn't care with these functions, because they are just the (low-level) internal part of the API; in OpenCV 3.0 they are also referenced in some functions, e.g. [`cv::magnitude()`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/063e4004ba0c103318aaf96c48eee6217865db9a/modules/core/src/mathfuncs.cpp#L192) calls [`cv::hal::magnitude()`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/hal/include/opencv2/hal.hpp#L89) within itself. That is if OpenCV was built with NEON support then you will implicitly benefit by HAL.